# Windows 11 update error with Boot Camp

Tags: windows, bootcamp

The device is MacBookPro 14,3 (MacBook Pro 15-inch 2017). Windows 11 22H2 1702 is installed and running from a USB3 UASP disk without a problem otherwise. But I can't install any Windows updates, because it will fall back and give the `Install error 0x800f0922`.

Maybe this has something to do with this MBP not having a T2 chip. I also suspect that the problem is related to the recent update of UEFI Secure Boot DBX, and this device does not have UEFI Secure Books. Do I need to wait for the next major Windows version update to come out and overwrite the installation?

Comment: When googling `0x800f0922`, I find this error has occurred for Windows 10. Therefore, I would assume the error has nothing to do with not having a T2 chip. Why do you think so? Do you think perhaps that T2 is the same as TPM?

Comment: @David Anderson What I mean is that this problem is related to secure boot, because the release note of KB5012170 releases some information about this error, which is related to UEFI secure boot, and virtual machine software such as parallels also encounters related problems, which can only be updated by updating UEFI  Firmware solution, not to mention that only products with t2 chips support secure boot, since Apple no longer supports Windows 11, even t2 hasn't gotten a firmware update, 0x800f0922 I see as an unspecified error type, so you can't Google what works  solution out

Comment: I do not believe the secure boot offered by Apple through the T2 chip is the same as secure boot used by PCs. AFAIK, Apple never supported Windows 11 on any Intel Mac model. I have a 2013 iMac with UEFI booting Windows 11 Pro 22H2 installed on the internal SATA HDD. The activation state is shown as "Active". Windows Update shows "You're up to date". I have installed all optional updates. Update history shows KB5012170 has been installed. At least four additional updates have been installed since KB5012170. BitLocker is not being used. This Mac does not have a T2 chip.